# kernel panic after the upgrade

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel

after the today's upgrade of Ubuntu 16.04 I made restart and received "Kernel panic" during the system load attempt.

Is it possible to fix/recover it or required to reinstall ubuntu from the ground up? If possible to recover, could you walk me through?

last message: End Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00 [image]

Answer (score 1):

During the startup (grub menu) you can choose the old version of the kernel.

```
go to "*Advanced options for Ubuntu"
```

and choose the previous version.

Comment: tried all 6 veriants there:
3.19.0-58 / 3.19.0-65 / 3.19.0-66 both generic and generic recovery mode all fails with the kernel panic

Comment: Only to make sure I have the right understanding: "after the today's upgrade of Ubuntu 16.04" means you have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and you only made a upgrade to install suggested newer versions of software. right ? you did not upgrade from another Ubuntu Version to 16.04, right ?

Comment: What happend if you choose "Advanced options.. " --> one of the versions for recovery mode ? --> "failsafeX" mode ?

Comment: yes, few days ago i got pop-up to upgrade the ubuntu, and today decided to do it and got the "result". i enter advanced option and see there 6 variants 3 generic and same 3 but recovery mod. tried all of them and every fails with the kernel panic

Comment: Can you create a ubuntu live usb boot device and boot with this ?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have usb sticks  ... i gonna create bootable dvd and reinstall the system ... dont see other ways for now :(